# Urllib2 Error in pip under Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, urllib2

I have some trouble running pip form ActiveState Python 2.7.2 under Windows. We use a proxy, which might 
be part of the issue. The proxy is a non-authenticating proxy. The proxy settings from the system, 
manually in e.g. Firefox or with some simple Python code work fine:

This works as expected:

```
urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com', proxies={'http': 'http://proxy:port'})
```

It gives a response with header information from google.com:

```
<addinfourl at 61539976L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x00000000042924F8>>
```

With the proxy being set in the `http_proxy`  environment variable I run

```
pip install loremipsum
```

I get

```
    Downloading/unpacking loremipsum
      Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/loremipsum: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo
failed>
      Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/loremipsum when looking for download links for loremipsum
      Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
      Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for loremipsum
      Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
      Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/loremipsum/: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
      Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/loremipsum/ when looking for download links for loremipsum
      Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement loremipsum
    No distributions at all found for loremipsum
    Exception information:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ActiveState\ActivePython\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 126,  in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ActiveState\ActivePython\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 222, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\ActiveState\ActivePython\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 954, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\ActiveState\ActivePython\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for loremipsum
```

The error 11004 seems to indicate a name resolution problem, which behind a proxy should be a problem with 
proxy access (or ignorance).

I can test a similar setup (http_proxy variable, same proxy, different Python) under Linux. Running the above command works nicely.
Also accessing the URL in a browser on the Windows machine works (shows a set of egg and zip files).

I walked the `pip` code to find where it misses an ran the code in an interactive session. I found that 
in `C:\ActiveState\ActivePython\lib\site-packages\pip\downloads.py` basically all downloading preparation
and action happens. In `setup()` (line 125) the `ProxyHandler` is prepared and and `opener` constructed, which is 
stored in `urllib2` to be used by further calls. When running interactively I found that adding an entry 
for a `https` proxy was needed. I also added the printing of debug information. This gave me in an interactive 
run in iPython:

```
In [1]: import urllib2

In [2]: proxy='proxy:port'

In [3]: proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": proxy, "ftp": proxy, "https": proxy})

In [4]: opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.CacheFTPHandler, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debugle
vel=1), urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1))

In [5]: urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

The proxy for `ftp`, `http` and `https` is indeed the same. I aslo checked with some printouts that all
code handling commandline parameters, etc. did not mess with the proxy. The proxy is stored the same way in 
`downloads.py` as simplified above (read from the http_proxy variable).

After figuring out the URL to fetch the package from pip goes to `__call__()` at line 74.

First a request is constructed using:

```
In [6]: url = urllib2.Request('http://pypi.python.org/simple/loremipsum', headers={'Accept-encoding': 'identity'})
```

then the request is used with `urllib2.urlopen(url)`:

```
In [7]: response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
send: 'GET http://pypi.python.org/simple/loremipsum HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pypi.python.org\r\nUser-Agent: Pyth
on-urllib/2.7\r\nConnection: close\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n'
header: Server: Varnish
header: Retry-After: 0
header: Location: https://pypi.python.org/simple/loremipsum
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Accept-Ranges: bytes
header: Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 16:41:39 GMT
header: Via: 1.1 varnish
header: X-Served-By: cache-fra1234-FRA
header: X-Cache: MISS
header: X-Cache-Hits: 0
header: X-Timer: S1407861699.491394,VS0,VE0
header: Connection: close
header: Age: 0
send: 'CONNECT pypi.python.org:443 HTTP/1.0\r\n'
send: '\r\n'
send: 'GET /simple/loremipsum HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pypi.python.org\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\nConne
ction: close\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n'
header: Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 16:41:40 GMT
header: Server: nginx/1.6.0
header: Location: /simple/loremipsum/
header: Cache-Control: max-age=600, public
header: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
header: Via: 1.1 varnish
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Accept-Ranges: bytes
header: Via: 1.1 varnish
header: Age: 44282
header: X-Served-By: cache-iad2135-IAD, cache-fra1231-FRA
header: X-Cache: MISS, HIT
header: X-Cache-Hits: 0, 1
header: X-Timer: S1407861700.831757,VS0,VE0
header: Connection: close
send: 'CONNECT pypi.python.org:443 HTTP/1.0\r\n'
send: '\r\n'
send: 'GET /simple/loremipsum/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pypi.python.org\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\nConn
ection: close\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Tue, 12 Aug 2014 16:41:41 GMT
header: Server: nginx/1.6.0
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: X-PYPI-LAST-SERIAL: 794358
header: Cache-Control: max-age=600, public
header: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
header: Via: 1.1 varnish
header: Content-Length: 913
header: Accept-Ranges: bytes
header: Via: 1.1 varnish
header: Age: 67708
header: X-Served-By: cache-iad2121-IAD, cache-fra1231-FRA
header: X-Cache: HIT, HIT
header: X-Cache-Hits: 1, 1
header: X-Timer: S1407861701.174694,VS0,VE0
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding
header: Connection: close
```

This seems to be an ok answer. I have the very same code in pip and yet it fails.

What am I missing? Why is my interactive session working and pip isn't?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't [specify the proxy](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip.html?highlight=proxy#cmdoption--proxy) to pip?

EDIT: summary of the comments: proxy was specified, by ENV `HTTP_PROXY`, but didn't work
at first, and works now.

I looked a bit into urllib, and there is code to handle the windows registry settings by 
default. There is `getproxies()`, which returns `getproxies_environment() or getproxies_registry()`, so you *should* have been OK already without any modifications to
the EMV *or* the command line.

Comment: I had the proxy in the http_proxy environment variable. This does the same. I checked for the proxy setting actually be used when setting up the ProxyHandler.

Comment: Updated the question to mention http_proxy variable use.

Comment: Since Linux and Windows are two kind of a thing, I could speculate whether there could be anything wrong with the env which is handed to pip or the code within python (or pip) handling it on the windows side of the universe. Give it a shot with the --proxy option...

Comment: Actually they both do the same. In `setup()` in `download.py` first the command line parameter is evaluated and if not set HTTP_PROXY is used.
I also tested this. The behavior is consistent.
(Un)fortunately I see a different behavior today. It works (both ways, environment variable and command line parameter). I am obviously missing another side effect.

Comment: sorry for insisting ;) where did you set HTTP_PROXY yesterday? Via windows system properties? You did restart your CMD shell afterwards?

Comment: I did set the variable in the shell (cmd.exe) with `set`. The behavior between setting it and removing it again was reproducible and consistent.
System properties have a proxy setting as well (as set in the Windows registry via IE's proxy dialog). I am under the impression though that no effort is made to read this. I did not look into the urllib2 sources though.

Comment: no idea what went wrong, but registry *is* also an option (updated answer)